# Not getting data in kinetic js throught JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, canvas

i am stuck in passing data from php to kineticjs throught json below is the code

```
$arrParams = array('images' =>$images, 'captions' => $content);
init({"container":"slider","data":<?php echo json_encode($arrParams); ?>});
```

i want to pass the above Json array in my below given coded kineticjs code

```
var data;
var canvasWidth;
var canvasHeight;
var stage;
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var imageNodes = [];
var imageObjects = [];
var imageBox = [];
var captionBox = [];
var textNodes = [];
var totalObjects = 0;
var objectLoaded = 0;

var currentSlide = false;
var defaultPosition = [];
var rightCardPosition = [];
var leftCardPosition = [];

function init(config) {
    canvasWidth = config.width | 600;
    canvasHeight = config.height | 300;

    defaultPosition["x"] = canvasWidth / 4;
    defaultPosition["y"] = canvasHeight + 5;

    leftCardPosition["start"] = [];
    leftCardPosition["end"] = [];
    leftCardPosition["start"]["x"] = (canvasWidth / 3) - 180;
    leftCardPosition["start"]["y"] = canvasHeight - 260;
    leftCardPosition["end"]["x"] = (canvasWidth + 100);
    leftCardPosition["end"]["y"] = -250;

    rightCardPosition["start"] = [];
    rightCardPosition["end"] = [];
    rightCardPosition["start"]["x"] = (canvasWidth / 3) + 160;
    rightCardPosition["start"]["y"] = canvasHeight - 300;
    rightCardPosition["end"]["x"] = (canvasWidth + 100);
    rightCardPosition["end"]["y"] = -250;

    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: config.container,
        width: canvasWidth,
        height: canvasHeight
    });

    totalObjects = data.images.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.images.length; i++) {
        totalObjects += data.captions[i].length;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.images.length; i++) {
        loadImage(data.images[i]);
        loadCaption(data.captions[i]);
    }
}
```

I am getting error like  in the line

`totalObjects = data.images.length;`

data is undefine... which means images is not pass from the json array

Comment: where are you assigning `data` a value?

Comment: I am assigning data in my .php file and passing with the use of json

Comment: Yeah but the `data` variable in your javascript does not automatically obtain the value from the JSON.  As you have it, you never give `data` a value, so it is `undefined`.

Comment: So how do i assign value to data and where do i have to assign value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encoding the JSON with PHP, now you just need to parse it with JavaScript and store it in your `data` variable.

```
data = JSON.parse(config.data);
```

Put this at the start of your `init` function and it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks dude... i had done the same thing init({data:<?php json_encode(array())?> })

and in java script i got data by using "config.data"